# What are /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/ and ~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/ for?

Tags: macos, browser-addons, plugins, browser-plugin

I see a lot of old crufty stuff in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/ and ~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/. Doesn't each browser manage its own plugins in independent application-specific directories?

Comment: What do you mean by general plugin area ? Is that a directory ?

Comment: I clarified my question now.

Comment: Yes they do. This ~/Library/Internet Plug-ins/ is for **Safari** under your Library.